# Slow performance drawing a circle made from JLabels

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, algorithm, jframe

I have made a simple program. 
It takes a radius and creates a circle.
The problem is that it's too slow with big numbers, 
like if `Radius` is `100` it takes ~1 minute
(I have a fast computer).
I assume the problem is in the line:

```
 pane.add(c[a][b]);
```

This is the program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mycircle extends JFrame
{
mycircle (int Radius)
{
    this.setTitle("Circle Generator - By Joe & Doe");
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,Radius*2+1));

    JLabel[][]c=new JLabel[Radius*2+1][Radius*2+1];
    for (int a=0; a<c.length; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<c[0].length; b++)
        {
            c[a][b]=new JLabel();
            c[a][b].setOpaque(true);
            pane.add(c[a][b]);
        }
    }

    c[Radius][Radius].setBackground(Color.black);
    double y;
    for (double x=-Radius; x<=Radius+1; x+=0.01)
    {
        y=Math.sqrt(Radius*Radius-x*x);
        c[(int)y+Radius][(int)x+Radius].setBackground(Color.black);
        c[(int)-y+Radius][(int)x+Radius].setBackground(Color.black);
    }
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(Math.min(Radius*30,850), Math.min(Radius*30,850));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter Radius");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    new mycircle (in.nextInt());
    in.close();
}
}
```

Is there a faster solution?
If so, is it using `JFrame` or Multithreading?

Comment: Why are you using GUI components to draw a circle? They were certainly not meant for this particular use. What is the motivation?

Comment: _"if Radius=100 it takes~1 minute..."_ For that you create 201*201=40,401 `JLabels`... **40 thousand UI components...** That's why.

Comment: _"Is there a faster solution?_" Yes, don't use UI components arranged in the shape you want to draw, instead use [Swing Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).